# How to change default time for scheduling messages in Slack?

Tags: slack

I often use scheduled messages in Slack. The default is 9:00AM, but I always schedule them to 8:00AM. Is there a way to change the default so I don't have to use custom every time?

I have installed it via Snap in Ubuntu.

Answer (score 2):

No, there is [no way to do this at the moment](https://forums.slackcommunity.com/s/question/0D53a000096BByjCAG/is-there-a-way-to-change-the-default-message-schedule-time-it-defaults-to-9am-but-i-use-to-schedule-discussions-i-want-to-have-first-thing-in-the-morning-with-my-directs-but-they-get-in-at-730-and-i-have-to-set-that-on-each-message?language=en_US).
Slack is apparently working on that, but I guess we'll have to wait a bit longer.

Comment: Fair enough. Thanks.